# Testing for UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString existence with Swift

Tags: ios, ios7, swift

On iOS 8 Apple gave us the possibility to go to the App Settings right from our app, using the Constant UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.URLWithString(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))`

There's a code to test if this Constant exists on iOS 7, but it uses ObjC and pointes. Apple did this on their code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AppPrefs/Listings/RootViewController_m.html

How can I make something like this using Swift?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Swift:

```
switch UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare("8.0.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) {
  case .OrderedSame, .OrderedDescending:
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.URLWithString(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))
  case .OrderedAscending:
    //Do Nothing.
}
```

In Objective-C:

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

Comment: @Tsuharesu - I added a Swift answer. It's not pretty but it works.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did answer too :)

Comment: How can I navigate back to my app from settings app ??

Comment: "if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL)" gives an error in Xcode 6.3 because it is always true. (The & being the problem)

Instead, use "if (UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil)".

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same as checking for a Constant, but if you know the API version that contains the Constant (in my case, iOS 8), there are some techniques: http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/

One of them is:

```
switch UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare("8.0.0", options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch) {
case .OrderedSame, .OrderedDescending:
    println("iOS >= 8.0")
case .OrderedAscending:
    println("iOS < 8.0")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use #available:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!);
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
};
```